# Let $Q:=[0,2] \times [0,2]$ ; then how to evaluate ${\int\int}_Q\lfloor x+y\rfloor dxdy$ ?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $Q:=[0,2] \times [0,2]$ ; then how to evaluate ${\int\int}_Q\lfloor x+y\rfloor dxdy$ ? where $\lfloor . \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer function . 
Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Aside from a set of measure $0$, $\lfloor x+y \rfloor + \lfloor (2-x)+(2-y)\rfloor = 3$, so the integral is $\frac12 \times 3 \times 2^2 = 6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will generalize this result for $n$ variables.  In this solution, I will denote $\{x\} = x-\lfloor x \rfloor$.

**Claim.**  Let $Q$ be $[0,2] \times [0,2] \times \cdots \times [0,2]$, where there are $n$ variables.

We have $$\int \int \cdots \int_{Q} \lfloor x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n \rfloor dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_n = (2n-1)2^{n-1}$$

For this problem, we have $n=2$, giving $(2 \cdot 2 -1) 2^{2-1} = 6$.

The core of my proof of this claim is the following lemma.

**Lemma.** Let $k$ be any real constant. We have $$\int_0^2 \lfloor x+k \rfloor \text{  }dx= 2k+1$$

**Note.** The proof of this lemma opens up more possible generalizations - in this case, changing $[0,2]$ to arbitrary interval $[a,b]$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**Proof of Lemma.** We have $$\int_0^2 \lfloor x+k \rfloor \text{  }dx= \int_0^{1-\{k\}} \lfloor x+k \rfloor \text{  }dx + \int_{1-\{k\}}^{2-\{k\}} \lfloor x+k \rfloor \text{  }dx + \int_{2-\{k\}}^2 \lfloor x+k \rfloor \text{  }dx$$ $$=\lfloor k \rfloor (1-\{k\})+(\lfloor k \rfloor + 1)+(\lfloor k \rfloor + 2) \{k\} = 2 \lfloor k \rfloor + 2\{k\}+1=2k+1$$ as desired. This concludes the proof. $\blacksquare$

**Proof of Claim.** Now we have $$\int \int \cdots \int_{Q} \lfloor x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n \rfloor \text{  }dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_n$$ $$= \int_0^2 \int_0^2 \cdots \int_0^2 2(x_2+x_3+\cdots x_n)+1 \text{  }dx_2 dx_3 \cdots dx_n$$ $$=\int_0^2 \int_0^2 \cdots \int_0^2 2x_2 \text{  } dx_3 dx_4 \cdots dx_n dx_2 + \int_0^2 \int_0^2 \cdots \int_0^2 2x_3 \text{  } dx_4 dx_5 \cdots dx_n dx_2 dx_3 + \cdots  $$ $$+\int_0^2 \int_0^2 \cdots \int_0^2 1 \text{  }dx_2 dx_3 dx_4 \cdots dx_n$$ $$= \int_0^2 2^{n-1} x_2 \text{  } dx_2 + \int_0^2 2^{n-1}x_3 \text{  }dx_3 + \cdots + \int_0^2 2^{n-1} x_n \text{  }dx_n+2^{n-1}$$ $$= 2^{n-1} \cdot 2 \cdot (n-1) + 2^{n-1} = (2n-1)2^{n-1}$$

This gives our conclusion. Check easily that this equation holds for $n=1$ as well. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

Area of $x+y<1$ in $[0,2]\times[0,2]$ = $1\over2$.

Area of $x+y<2$ in $[0,2]\times[0,2]$ = $2$.

Area of $x+y<3$ in $[0,2]\times[0,2]$ = $4-\frac12=\frac72$.

${\int\int}_Q\lfloor x+y\rfloor dxdy=(2-\frac12)\times1+(\frac72-2)\times2+(4-\frac72)\times3=4\times3-(\frac12+2+\frac72)=6$