# Can't solve double integral with Gauss mark

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

evaluate the integral

$$\int \int_D [x+y]dA \qquad , D=[1,3]\times[2,5]$$

(let [x] denote the greatest integer in x )

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It could be that in this case you can just calculate the integral graphically, since in certain regions the function gets a constant value. Perhaps draw a picture and just sum the different areas together?

Comment: What's a Gauss mark?

Comment: @J.G. See explanation in the introduction of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions (I didn't know either).

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following figure displaying surface with equation

$$z=[x+y]$$

[image]

Nice staircase, isn't it ? A projection is as follows :

[image]

It remains to compute the volumes of the different [prismatic shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_(geometry)) using formula : volume  =  base area times height) and add them.

Hint : The computation can be eased by "piling up" some of these prismatic shapes. For example the two extreme ones, under the form $V=B\times h=1 \times (3+7)$.

Edit : in fact, I just saw a very similar question : [Let $Q:=[0,2] \times [0,2]$ ; then how to evaluate ${\int\int}_Q\lfloor x+y\rfloor dxdy$ ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1559233). A comment of Achille Hui was very enlightning, extending the idea above : just pile up a copy of the global given volume, upside down and reversed at 180°, on the first one in order to obtain a parallelepiped (a "brick") with volume $2 \times 3 \times 10=60$... and finally divide by $2$.

Comment: No reaction, a day after ?