# A problem about measure theory and integration

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

**Note:** All the definitions, problems or theorems here are about functions $\mathscr{R}-$integrable.

> **Problem:** Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(t)=\lfloor{t\rfloor}$ and let $Q=[0,2] \times [0,2]$. Prove that $h$ defined by $h(x,y)=f(x+y)$ is $\mathscr{R}-$integrable  on $Q$.

> **Definition:** Let $A$ be a bounded subset of the plane. The set $A$ is said to have content zero if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite set of rectangles whose union contains $A$ and the sum of whose areas does not exceed $\epsilon$.

> **Theorem:** Let $f$ be a function defined and bounded on $Q=[a,b]\times [c,d]$. If the set $D_{f}$ of discontinuities of $f$ in $Q$ is a *set of content zero*  then the double integral $$\int \int_{Q}f$$there exists.

**My attempt:** We need to prove that $h: [0,2] \times [0,2] \subset \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(x,y)=\lfloor{x+y\rfloor}$ is integrable on $[0,2] \times [0,2]$. So, we need to show that:

1. $f$ is bounded on $Q=[0,2] \times [0,2]$.
2. Let $D_{h}$ the set of discontinuities of $h$ in $Q$, so $D_{h}$ is a *set of content zero*

Now, $[1]$ we have that for all $(x,y) \in [0,2]\times [0,2]=Q$,  $$|\lfloor{x+y\rfloor}|\overbrace{=}^{definition}|\max\{k \in \mathbb{Z}: k \leq x+y\}|\leq 4$$
So $f$ is bounded on $Q$. **Is it correct?**

Now, $[2]$, we can see that $Q=[0,2] \times [0,2] \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$, now I need to show that $\forall \epsilon>0$ there is a finite set of rectangles whose union contains $Q$ and the sum of whose areas does not exceed $\epsilon$.

**New attemp:** We can see that [image]so we can say that $$D_{h}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x+y=0,1,2,3\}$$Now, $h$ is continues in $[0,2]\times [0,2]$ except in $x+y=0,1,2,3$.

But, I don't understand the *hint*.

Comment: When you say "integrable" you should specify.  *Lebesgue integrable* is essentially trivial.  So your question must be *Riemann integrable*.

Comment: Ok, thank you! The problem is about Riemann integrable.

Comment: It's problem has a relation with: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1559431/798113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: $f$ is continuous at all points of $[0,4]$ except the integer points. So the points of discontinuity of $h$ are contained in $\cup_{i=0,1,2,3,4} \{(x,y): x+y=i\}$. Let us show that $\{(x,y): x+y=c\}$ has content $0$ for any real number $c$. Partition $[0,2]$ into $2n$ equal subintervals. With $(\frac i n, c-\frac  i n)$ as its mid-point  draw  a rectangle whose side are of  lengths $\frac   4n$. The total areas of these rectangles is $\frac {16} {n^{2}} (2n) <\epsilon $ if $n$ is large enough. Now consider any point $(x,c-x)$ in the given set. There exists $i$ such that $\frac {i-1} n \leq x \leq \frac i n$. Now verify that $(x,c-x)$ belongs to the rectangle which has $(\frac i n, c-\frac  i n)$ as it mid-point. It follows that our rectangles cover the set  $\{(x,y): x+y=c\}$.

Comment: Is $D_{f}=\{(x,y):x+y=c, c\in \mathbb{R}\}$? and why $h$ is continuous on $[0,4]$...?, is it same that if I say that  $h$ is continuous on $[0,2]\times [0,2]$?

Comment: @Ramanujan You are not interested in $D_f$. It is $D_h$ you have to look at. $D_h=\{(x,y): x+y \in \{0,1,2,3,4 \}$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's a typo. I should write $D_{h}$. But, when you say "$h$ is continuous at all points $[0,4]$ except the integer points  " is it the same if I say "$h$ is continuous at all points $[0,2]\times [0,2]$except the integer points ?

Comment: @Ramanujan Sorry, I had a typo in the very first sentence. I typed $h$ instead of $f$.

Comment: @Ok, so the correct is "$h$ is continuous at all points $[0,2]\times [0,2]$ except the integers points"?

Comment: I don't understand that part.

Comment: $h$ is continuous at $(x,y)$ if $x+y$ is not one of the numbers $0,1,2,3,4$. This follows from the fact that composition of  continuous maps is continuous. Compose $h$ with $(x,y) \to x+y$). @Ramanujan

Comment: Thanks so much!